# Efficient one-letter-difference string comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, string-comparison

Let's assume I have a table [data] with a column [address] (not a PK, but I could isolate it so if need be). I want to know possible [address] pairs such that one string equals the other except for one non-numeric character. How do I implement this in a way that has good performance?

My current solution is to have a `numbers` table and then 
`inner join` the table with itself

`on numbers.value <= len(data1.address) and stuff(data1.address,numbers.value,1,'') = e2.address`

I was just wondering if there is anything faster. Could maybe a cursor(through the possible positions of the different character), in this rare occasion, prove faster?

As long as the logic is explained, the answer need not have real code. Pseudocode will do finely, too.

`sql` tag included because of a probable more general solution.

Comment: Your chances of getting a good answer will increase dramatically if you would provide [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and expected results.

Comment: Do you have to do it in SQL? There are better tools for this sort of thing.

Comment: You may find a search for 'Levenshtein distance' helpful. It's a measure of difference between two strings. You'll turn up some SQL implementations.

Comment: You're missing an obvious optimisation that only rows `where LEN(data1.address) = LEN(e2.address) + 1` will join

Comment: Rereading, I like your solution and find it hard to imagine anything would be much faster. You may get some mileage out of sorting the data appropriately perhaps by bringing out the length into a separate indexed field and only doing the comparison where the lengths differ by 1.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . I don't think there is an efficient way to do this in relational databases, although there might be some tricks with n-grams.